# Adding custom HTML/CSS to a client's existing store in Shopify

Tags: json, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Hi I'm totally new to Shopify and I'm having trouble grasping some basic stuff. So I have a client with an existing store and I was asked to design a landing page. I did all the html and css in vscode before I really took a look at Shopify and I want to know what the best way to create the page using the code I've already written would be. So far it looks like I have to create a custom template and then manually edit the JSON file but I have no idea how to work with JSON / how to link custom styles to that file. Can I create a template using Liquid and then refer ONLY  that template to a custom styles sheet? I don't want to update the stores theme file before I know that this is all going to work / I'm wary of any kind of accidental overlap of tags and classes.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: all you need is on this page https://shopify.dev/themes/getting-started

Comment: i have also tried shopify . read the docs or search for a yt channel called " coding with jan" i learnt most of the things from him regarding shopify

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. You can create sections with a preset block that can be added to the customizer. Learn the basics of schema and a little bit of liquid. Study the existing themes in free theme dawn. You will be able to figure it out. There is plenty of youtube channel to learn the basics also Shopify document has strong details. You can refer to it. Hope this helps https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBukJ6yWzTdlLKY9QKhv-Mg You can try his skillshare class to understand the basics.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUa4yMJ3mVquTL5TIpxatqQ This guy also explain it quiet easily. Even I like coding with Jan. He is too good